# boto3: Table.get_item doesn't return items

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I execute this code in my local machine.

```
import boto3
boto3.resource('dynamodb').Table('table_name').get_item(Key={'id': 'id'})
```

And it returns this.

```
{'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  'HTTPStatusCode': 200,
  'HTTPHeaders': {'server': 'Server',
   'date': 'Sat, 29 Aug 2020 08:23:07 GMT',
   'content-type': 'application/x-amz-json-1.0',
   'content-length': '2',
   'connection': 'keep-alive',
   'x-amzn-requestid': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
   'x-amz-crc32': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'},
  'RetryAttempts': 0}}
```

How can I get an item from dynamodb with boto3?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The expected response of GetItem should look like the below syntax.

```
{
    'Item': {
        'AlbumTitle': {
            'S': 'Songs About Life',
        },
        'Artist': {
            'S': 'Acme Band',
        },
        'SongTitle': {
            'S': 'Happy Day',
        },
    },
    'ResponseMetadata': {
        '...': '...',
    },
}
```

As you have `ResponseMetadata` and it returned a 200 this indicates that the request to DynamoDB was indeed successful but that no item with key `id` had a value of `id`.

You should validate that the value being passed in is a real ID value.

Comment: 204 would make more sense to me. How do you validate the `id`?